# Recovering lost .sty files

Tags: luatex, moderncv

Is it somehow possible to recover a custom .sty file from generated output resource ?

I explain myself, I used to modify the sty file from `moderncv` to match my needs. I backup all my tex files and everything needed to not lose my work. However I missed the fact that the `.sty` files were not in the same directory (somewhere in /etc/latex/...) and didn't backup this folder.

Thing is I used this `.sty` to generate lots of pdf and have all the different files (`.log`, `.dvi`, `.out`, `.aux`, `.tex` and `.ps`) and wondered if base on that it would be possible to regenerate the lost `.sty` file.

What do you think ?

Best Regards,

Nicko

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try macumba? `;-)` Seriously, if the files are gone, there's no way to recover them from the output you have: it would be like recovering the gasoline knowing the car travel you did.

Comment: Ok thanks, let close this as non relevant (or as stupid question as you wish)

Comment: Not stupid at all, of course. I hope you didn't mind about my joke. I sympathize with you, but it's really impossible. One can *guess* something by looking at the output and the `.tex` files, though. Having worked yourself on the modified `.sty` files, I think you can get to something.

Comment: Yes that was actually my point, which relevant information could I take back to reconstitute my `.sty` ? No issue with the joke `;)` well deserved even if I didn't get the reference to "macumba" (it's a famous club here near Geneva)

Comment: Macumba, candomblé, voodoo: take your pick. `;-)` Since it seems your changes are about `moderncv`, comparing input and output with the standard, you might be able to remember what changes you did. But I'm afraid I can give you no more than this.

Comment: Yep, thanks anyway, how can I close the question ?

Comment: I guess you can delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is not possible: it would be like divining the fully detailed recipe of the *Sachertorte* from the slice you get at a café. Not everything is lost: if you have PDF or DVI output files to examine, some clues can be found, as you know you just modified macros of `moderncv`.

Compare with standard output from the sources you have, take note of the undefined commands (which were defined in the lost `.sty` file), perform some [macumba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macumba), [candomblé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candombl%C3%A9), [voodoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voodoo)<sup>1</sup> and you may get some result.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Just joking. `;-)`</sup>